# Django form do nothing on hosting?

Tags: python, django, sendmail

I have form in my django app, that send_email in ajax. But when i have deployed this on my hosting, it doesn't react for submit... i even dont understand how i can debug it.
I have remove function send_mail and just trying to make redirect or even just HttpResponse to submit, but when clicking submit it doest work and dont showing any errors to my console..

Here is code:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms


class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    user_name = forms.CharField(label='name', max_length=128, required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', max_length=128, required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(label='subject', max_length=128, required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(label='message', widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, redirect
from .forms import ContactForm

def contacts(request):
    form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        user_name = request.POST.get('user_name', '')
        email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        subject = request.POST.get('subject', '')
        message = request.POST.get('message', '')
        return HttpResponse('Success!')
    ctx = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'contacts.html', ctx)
```

**contacts.html**

```
<form method="post" id="contact-form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% bootstrap_form form %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn button">
  </div>
</form>
```

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Where is the line/lines to send the email? In the if inside contacts you are only getting the fields and nothing else.

Comment: If you look at your browser tools, is a request being sent when you submit the form? Do you have JavaScript on the page that could prevent the form from being submitted?

Comment: Are you getting the `Success!` message in HTML?

Comment: show the url and where is the action in form tag, use FormView , Check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/